# Battery misinformation

Tags: battery

I have a Droid Turbo (called Moto Maxx here in Brazil) which started to show a strange behavior. With normal use, its battery decreases til 53% percent, and the phone power off suddenly.

When the phone is still with 54% of battery, the battery widgets indicates a 3.4V and looking at the battery statistics on the settings, the sum of the power consumption since the last full recharge is very close to the 3900mAh.

It looks the battery actually is doing ok, but the system isn´t calculating the battery charge correctly.

I´ve tried some tutorials where I have to leave the battery drain off completely, and so, do a full recharge, and a full discharge, but the problem persists. So, how could I effectively 'reset' this battery statistics?

Comment: If you let the battery drain completely, plug it in below 53%, and try to turn on the phone, does it display the percentage as nearly dead?

Comment: I´m going to test it.

Comment: Try the battery recalibration described here https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-165413/

Comment: @beeshyams I tried this procedure already. Ethan Actually it neve get below 53% without shutdown.